# Consuming WS-Security protected webservice with WCF client

Tags: wcf, web-services, cxf, ws-security, x509

I'm trying to consume a soap webservice using a WCF/C# client.

The server's wsdl defines its security policy in its wsdl file like this:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BindingSecPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
     ...
```

This policy is referenced in the binding definition.

Now I'm trying to setup a client in WCF that can talk to this service. I created a new .NET 4.5 console application, added a service reference, got visual studio to autogenerate classes for my service.

This is how I'm trying to invoke my service.

```
WSDualHttpBinding binding = new WSDualHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
binding.ClientBaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5555");
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:9080/CustomerServicePort");
CustomerServiceClient client = new CustomerServiceClient(binding, address);
foreach (customer c in client.getCustomersByName("foo")) {
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
client.Close();
Console.ReadKey();
```

The reason I'm using a dual binding is that the wsdl also defines WS-RM as a requirement. I'm aware that I'm not specifying any certificates at the moment, so this setup cannot really work. 
When I run this code I get an exception saying that the policy is not supported:

```
Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: An exception was thrown in a call to a policy import extension.
Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElementImporter
Error: An unsupported security policy assertion was detected during the security policy import: <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy">
    <sp:InitiatorToken>
        <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference />
                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:X509Token>
        </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:InitiatorToken>
    <sp:RecipientToken>
        <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/I...

XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://customerservice.example.com']/wsdl:binding[@name='CustomerServiceServiceSoapBinding']    C:\projects\cxf-samples\wsrm-client-csharp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Service References\CustomerService\Reference.svcmap  1   1   b2bclientcsharp
```

This is happening before it is actually checking if I'm supplying certificates and all that, so I didn't bother setting this up yet. According to Microsofts documentation WS-SecurityPolicy 1.2 is supported and they even given an example policy which is quite similar to the one the service is defining.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738565.aspx and search for "Using X.509 Certificates for Service Authentication".

Any general ideas what I'm doing wrong here ?

Cheers, 
Andy